# View XML feed source in Firefox

Tags: xml, firefox, rss, google-chrome, atom-feed

When I click on an XML feed in Firefox it automatically detects this and asks how I would like to subscribe. Is there an easy way to just see the raw feed in Firefox?

This is simple in Google's Chrome browser, since it doesn't do anything. But I am guessing a future version will handle it as Firefox does.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just discovered one workaround, quite by chance. If you click on 'view source' for the page that contains the RSS link, and then click on the RSS link *inside* view source, it will take you to the source of the RSS...

Answer (score 2):

The simplest solution I have found (other than right click a feed and select 'view source') to view raw XML is to prepend the address with `view-source:`.

For example, in Firefox:

```
view-source:http://feeds.bbci.co.uk/news/business/rss.xml?edition=int
```

will show the XML. Whereas

```
http://feeds.bbci.co.uk/news/business/rss.xml?edition=int
```

will show the page to add an RSS feed.

Answer (score 1):

You should just be able to right click, and view page source.

Comment: this just gives you the source to the 'add to google' page, right?